# Source Insight type editor with tabbed windows and dividers?

Tags: c++, c, source-insight, tabbed-interface, tabbed-view

I really like the set up of Source Insight, it has a context window for one click understanding of function calls and variables, and a relations window for where functions are called in a project and where variables are used in the project.

It is very good for jumping around in a project and understanding the use of variables, but one thing that's missing is tabbed windows and dividers. It is stuck in the one source file, one window phase of IDE development, before tabs and vertical/horizontal dividers got popular.

It is also very good at finding references for variables and functions, much better than code blocks, codewright, and eclipse (really tried all of them).

Does anyone know or have a set up similar to Source Insight but with Tabs and dividers?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this very nice CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32209/a-File-Switch-Tabbar-for-Source-Insight.  Doesn't require any effort, just run the executable, and let it do it's magic.

Keep in mind, it's a **very** immature project and it might even crash SI if you annoy it (i.e. it might crash if you double click a tab to close it). On the other hand it does the job. I've been using it for over 6 months now, and I've learned how to avoid its touchy parts, and am very happy with it.

Comment: New build of this tool is available at the author's blog -- TabSiPlus 0.99b2 build 1749: http://blog.csdn.net/orbit/article/details/7702472

Answer (score 0):

Source Insight 4 contains the capabilities you mentioned